# With mocha/chai how can i make it show lines skipped?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a failing unit test that is comparing two large arrays, and the output from mocha is partially skipped.

```
         "Qualifying/Commissions/Amount"
         "Qualifying/Other/Amount"
         "Qualifying/Overtime/Amount"
         "Qualifying/Total/Amount"
      -  "Factors/De/ ... Lines skipped
      +  "Factors/De/Base/Amount"
      +  "Factors/De/Bo ... Lines skipped
```

How do I get more of the lines that were skipped?  Pytest has a `-v` option for verbose.

This is the result of calling

```
expect(actual).to.deep.equal(expected)
```

where actual and expected are big ol' arrays of strings.

Versions:
"mocha": "^9.0.3",
"sinon-chai": "^3.5.0",
"chai": "~4.1",

Comment: Seems like you are using console reporter. I suggest you use another reporter e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome

Answer (score 3):

If you see this you need to update mocha to at least `v9.2.1` and then you can use `--reporter-option maxDiffSize=0`

From the docs:

> New in v9.2.1
>
> By default strings are truncated to 8192 characters before generating a diff. This is to prevent performance problems with large strings.
>
> It can however make the output harder to interpret when comparing large strings. Therefore it is possible to configure this value using --reporter-option maxDiffSize=[number].
>
> A value of 0 indicates no limit, default is 8192 characters.

Answer (score 1):

This one is pretty tricky, I met it as well.

**TL;DR**

go to node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js: 193
change     `const diffSize = 2048;` to a larger one.

**Details**

The reason they limit the line size is because this issue: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/3675

and they solved with this PR: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/4638

the code associated is:

```
 const diffSize = 2048;
    if (actual.length > diffSize) {
      actual = actual.substring(0, diffSize) + ' ... Lines skipped';
    }
    if (expected.length > diffSize) {
      expected = expected.substring(0, diffSize) + ' ... Lines skipped';
    }
```

Thus, you will need to modify the diffSize to a larger one.
Perhaps local dev only, try some patch hook if you wanna use it in other env.